# Google Places API Getting Image Flutter

Tags: api, flutter

I'm trying to make a weather app which gives you information about the weather of your location, I can get user location using geolocation and it's working, so with sending latitude and longitude to Google Places API, I want to get picture of the location where the user is. I wrote a function for it but having this error.Here Is the API doc https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

```
Exception has occurred.
RangeError (RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0)




     Future getImage(double lat, double long) async {
            //THIS FUNCTION SUPPOSED TOGENERATE PHOTO REFERENCE
            http.Response response = await http.get(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$lat,$long&radius=1500&key=$apiKeyImageCity");
            var data = response.body;
            String photoRef =
                jsonDecode(data)['results'][0]['photos'][0]['photo_reference'];
            
//with using photo ref trying to get actual image
http.Response image = await http.get(
                "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/photo?maxwidth=400&photoreference=$photoRef&key=$apiKeyImageCity");
            return image;
          }
```

OUTPUT OF DATA
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

```
I/flutter (31143): {
I/flutter (31143):    "html_attributions" : [],
I/flutter (31143):    "next_page_token" : "CqQCFgEAAAlw1Lhod46jN326VCclcpZ7M5BIK_aq57oyPW0rKwC65zpTHq0ZOz8OlX46OZS-_80kwd3lXbVPFIcsobdirbzYxilvVjzwozYTruylXZXpYC8c8gAkx84wK2splwrzHimr_0rb6AzNu-S8DVa9RTaxIJe3W9nu1ybN0YXBwpjKLj-qjtuUPZYAeKCkjM8tvtUKPtgLvMMDFLAKc90qvGJtTaSciqYObOxiGm86YE7JlHQlG1ZnE09BYAtMZWyz7Vbpnv4OE9fJjjlFsRR4mSIPlpggr0fnbFKJh6AA0ghtyCysB17MB6kWGCPAdy749cZQNH9AIEhEun_97E5DivN_JXnyr1SdA4XY-zcAI7xS-qVpvevRaFCgms41Oxmc_RIQR22nRF3VEmMnzvhw4HaD8BoUtqZFQDpEd69E3NteSBAUlsXKg7Y",
I/flutter (31143):    "results" : [
I/flutter (31143):       {
I/flutter (31143):          "geometry" : {
I/flutter (31143):             "location" : {
I/flutter (31143):                "lat" : 41.0082376,
I/flutter (31143):                "lng" : 28.9783589
I/flutter (31143):             },
I/flutter (31143):             "viewport" : {
I/flutter (31143):                "northeast" : {
I/flutter (31143):                   "lat" : 41.199239,
I/flutter (31143):                   "lng" : 29.4288049
I/flutter (31143):                },
I/flutter (31143):                "southwest" : {
I/flutter (31143):                   "lat" : 40.811404,
I/flutter (31143):                   "lng" : 28.595554
I/flutter (31143):                }
I/flutter (31143):             }
I/flutter (31143):          },
I/flutter (31143):          "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_ap
```

Comment: print(data) before creating photoRef, what do you get?

Comment: getting invalid request error but according to API documentation it's right

Comment: Try it on postman and see what you get.

Comment: i am able to get photoRef now correctly but getting error type 'Future<dynamic> is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: From what line?

Comment: solved problem with refactoring code thanks for the help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved

```
import 'package:clima/services/location.dart';
import 'package:clima/services/networking.dart';
import 'package:clima/utilities/constants.dart';

class CityImage {
  Location userLocation = new Location();
  Future<dynamic> getImageData() async {
    await userLocation.getCurrentLocation();
    NetworkHelper networkHelper = new NetworkHelper(
        "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${userLocation.latitude},${userLocation.longtitude}&radius=1500&key=$apiKeyImageCity");
    var imageData = await networkHelper.getData();
    return imageData;
  }
}



void getImage() async {
    CityImage cityImage = new CityImage();
    cityImageData = await cityImage.getImageData();
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) {
        return LocationScreen(
          weatherData: weatherDataLocation,
          imageData: cityImageData,
        );
      },
    ));
  }
```